# При разрешении экрана 1920 на 1080 python решает, что это 1536 на 864

Tags: python, pyqt5, экран

У меня разрешение монитора - **1920х1080**, но в питоне при выводе данных экрана при помощи каких либо  библиотек, он мне пишет, что разрешение **1536x864**, почему так? Использовал `win32api.GetSystemMetrics()`, в модулях `mouse`, `pygame`, `PyQt5`, `Tkinter` расширение измеряется так же. Для меня это не проблема, но мне интересно узнать, с чем это связано и почему так произошло.

Comment: Потому что в настройках системы накручен масштаб 125% например?

Comment: Да, теперь всё показывает правильные координаты. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Масштаб показывался не таким, какой установлен на компьютере потому, что масштаб дисплея на компьютере был установлен 125%.

Comment: в linux такого нет)